# How to add comment asking for commiting at the team provider plugin?

Tags: eclipse, svn

I make a commit via team provider and it does not ask for any commit comment... But it did in the past. Where is it configured?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I'm very sorry.
Preferences->Team->CVS->Promping